# Identify which screen is internal screen

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I'm using a `%Windir%\System32\displayswitch.exe` to change projection mode beetwen *internal* and *external*. Unfortunately - sometimes *internal* screen is not the screen, which I would like to be.

Is there any way to check which screen is recognized by OS as internal screen before I run displayswitch? Is it stored anywhere in registry?

Comment: Sorry for commenting five years later. Your question is the first search result that turns up when googling the problem. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

at Desktop > r-click > Display Settings > Multiple Display > Detect.

Number 1 is normally the internal screen.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Sometimes screen with id 2 is an internal screen

Comment: sorry.. it doesn't work for you.. it never happen to me happen to me before.. / :

Comment: I don't know if this would help.. I use "window + P" when I need to do fast projection mode switching.. It'll only become useless when I deal with 3 monitors..  good luck. [ :

Comment: Thanks, "window + P" invoking displayswitch.exe, but I need to know which display is internal before invoke it ;/

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful the free
[MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html),
which can display a "Primary" column having as values "Yes"/"No".
It can also set a monitor to Primary.

[image]

Comment: Primary monitor is not same as "internal" in displayswitch, it doesn't help me.

Comment: I have not been able to find any app that displays this info. I think you will need to find this visually.